# Creating a one sided buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer

I want a 3km buffer from a coastline but only on the seaward side. How would I accomplish this? I tried using difference but it didn't work

I initially got a geometry error which I fixed and still no good. The new layer (after using difference) just replicates the initial buffered layer as far as I can see.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the "one side buffer" under the tool dialog box, just search for the word buffer. It is under GDAL Vector Geoprocessing tools/algorithms. Take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

The dialog has a left/right option to choose from:

[image]